# How to implement a timer for a math quiz in python?

Tags: python-3.x, time

```
import random
import time
import pathlib
import hashlib
import operator

level = 1
score = 1


def sign_up():
    username = input("Enter a username: ")
    while True:
        password = input("Enter a password (6 character long): ")
        if len(password) < 6:
            password = input("Enter a password (6 character long): ")
        else:
            break
    hashed_password = hashlib.sha1(password.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
    # print(hashed_password)
    with open("credentials.txt", mode="w") as writable_password:
        writable_password.write(username+"\n")
        writable_password.write(hashed_password+"\n")

    log_in()


def log_in():
    print("Please, enter your usarname and password to sign in")
    username = input("Username: ")+"\n"

    while True:
        password = input("Password (6 character long): ")
        if len(password) < 6:
            password = input("Password (6 character long): ")
        else:
            break

    with open(".credentials.txt", mode="r") as credentials:
        user_data = credentials.readlines()
        for i in user_data:
            # print(i)
            if i == username and hashlib.sha1(password.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()+"\n" == user_data[user_data.index(i)+1]:
                print("You have succesfully signed in")
                start_game()
                break


def start_game():
    start = "ll"
    start = input("Please press any key to start the game")
    # print(start)
    if start != "ll" and level == 1:
        level_one()


overall = 0


def level_one():
    global score
    global overall
    if score <= 0:

        return print("Haha, You lost")
    answer = 0

    first_number = random.randint(1, 100)
    second_number = random.randint(1, 100)
    random_operator = random.choice(["+", "-"])
    if random_operator == "+":
        response = input(f"{first_number} + {second_number}: ")
        answer = first_number + second_number
        if int(response) == answer:
            score += 10
            overall += 10
            print(score)
            level_one()
        else:
            score -= 10
            print(score)
            level_one()

    else:
        response = input(f"{first_number} - {second_number}: ")
        answer = first_number - second_number
        if int(response) == answer:
            score += 10
            print(score)
            level_one()
        else:
            score -= 10
            print(score)
            level_one()
    # print(first_number, second_number, answer)

# def main():

# if __name__ = "__main__":
#     main()
# sign_up()
# log_in()
start_game()
```

I want to implement a timer for my math quiz. The user should have 2 minutes at the beginning and for each correct answer 10 seconds will be added. For wrong answers 6 sec will be removed. How can I do this with Python 3.8?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new methode and using the threading.Timer modul (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects):

```
from threading import Timer
global time_to_play
time_to_play=2*60        # in seconds
```

....

```
def check_for_end:
    if time_to_play == 0:              # time runs out
        print("You lose")
        exit(0)                        # exit program

    else:                                   # still playing
       t = Timer(2.0, check_for_end)  # start Timer wich runs the check methode in 2 sec
       t.start()
```

and now you just have to adjust the global variable `time_to_play` accordingly.
The Timer will check all 2 seconds, if `time_to_play` is 0